# How to find the optimal decoder that minimizes the probability of error?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Suppose that the signal $X$ is drawn as...

$$
X = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{with probability 1/2}} \\
0 & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{with probability 1/2}}
\end{cases}
$$

& the conditional pmf $P\left[Y = y\;|\;X = x\right]$ of $Y$ given $X$ is specified by...

$$
\begin{array}{l}
P\left[Y = 1\;|\;X = 1\right] = 1 \\
P\left[Y = 1\;|\;X = 0\right] = 1/2
\end{array}
$$

---

1. Find the optimal decoder $d\left(y\right)$ that minimizes the
   probability of error $P\left[X \ne d\left(Y\right)\right]$.
2. Find the associated probability of error.

---

Based on the information given, I constructed the following probability table...

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
   & X = 0       & X = 1       & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Total}} \\\hline
 Y = 1 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{4} \\\hline
 Y = 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0           & \frac{1}{4} \\\hline
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Total}} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 1
\end{array}
$$

Using the table, I have the answers to every conditional probability...

- $P\left[X = 0 | Y = 0\right] = 1$.
- $P\left[X = 0 | Y = 1\right] = 1/3$.
- $P\left[X = 1 | Y = 0\right] = 0$.
- $P\left[X = 1 | Y = 1\right] = 2/3$.
- $P\left[Y = 0 | X = 0\right] = 1/2$.
- $P\left[Y = 0 | X = 1\right] = 0$.
- $P\left[Y = 1 | X = 0\right] = 1/2$.
- $P\left[Y = 1 | X = 1\right] = 1$.

**From here, could you explain how to find $d\left(y\right)$ for this problem &, if you're feeling generous, any problem like it?**

---

FYI: This is not hw; I am practicing for a qualification exam.

Comment: BTW you have one error in your conditional probs.  $P(X=0 | Y= 0)$ should be $1$.

Comment: @antkam You're right, mb. Thanks for the good answer btw, I think I understand the concept now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, a decoder maps observed $Y$'s to guessed $X$'s, i.e. $d: \{0,1\} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$.  Or in other words, you are choosing $d(0)$ (what $X$ to guess when seeing $Y=0$) and $d(1)$ (what $X$ to guess when seeing $Y=1$).  And you want to minimize the prob of guessing wrong, i.e. when $d(Y)$ (i.e. the guess) $\neq X$ (i.e. the actual signal).

At this point, if you stare at the $2 \times 2$ probability table, it should be "really obvious" that you should guess $d(0) = 0$, because if you see $Y=0$ then it is certain that $X=0$.  The question is what to guess when seeing $Y=1$, but it should also be "somewhat obvious" :) that in that case you should guess $d(1) = 1$.  We will prove these rigorously now.

$$
\begin{align}
P(d(Y) \neq X) &= P(d(Y) \neq X | Y = 1) P(Y=1) + P(d(Y) \neq X | Y=0) P (Y=0)\\
&=P(d(1) \neq X | Y=1)P(Y=1) + P(d(0) \neq X | Y=0) P(Y=0)
\end{align}$$

Note that, as far as the minimization is concerned, $P(Y=1), P(Y=0)$ are constants.  Since we can choose $d(0), d(1)$ independently, we can minimize each term separately.  Formally we're doing this:

$$d(i) = \arg\min_{j \in \{0,1\}} P(j \neq X | Y = i) = \arg \max_{j \in \{0,1\}} P(j = X | Y = i)$$

I.e. for each case of $Y=i$, simply find the most probable $X$ (conditioned on $Y=i$).  I would say this is a general feature of all kinds of decoding.

First, $P(d(0) \neq X | Y = 0)$: Conditioned on $Y=0$, we have $X=0$ with certainty.  Nothing is more probable than certainty.  So we choose $d(0) = 0$.

Next, $P(d(1) \neq X | Y = 1)$: You can easily calculate that $P(X=1 | Y = 1) = {2 \over 3}$, and $P(X=0 | Y = 1) = {1 \over 3}$.  Since $X=1$ is more probable (conditioned on $Y=1$), we choose $d(1) = 1$.

With these optimal choices of $d(0) = 0, d(1) = 1$, the overall error prob is:

$$
\begin{align}
P(d(Y) \neq X) &= P(d(1) \neq X | Y=1)P(Y=1) + P(d(0) \neq X | Y=0) P(Y=0) \\
&= P(1 \neq X | Y=1)P(Y=1) + P(0 \neq X | Y=0) P(Y=0) \\
&=  {1 \over 3} \cdot {3 \over 4} + 0 \cdot {1 \over 4} = {1 \over 4}
\end{align}$$

Another way to find the overall error prob is to augment your table with your choices (remember that $d()$ is a deterministic function, depending on $Y$ only), and then realize the red entries are the cases when you guess wrong:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
   & X = 0       & X = 1       & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Total}} \\\hline
 Y = 1 \iff d(Y) = 1 & \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{4} \\\hline
 Y = 0 \iff d(Y) = 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \color{red}{0}           & \frac{1}{4} \\\hline
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{Total}} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 1
\end{array}

Comment: It should be possible for arg max to return a set (containing the values of x that produced equal probabilities); do you know of a common notation for denoting "arbitrarily select 1 element from resultant set of arg max"?

Comment: @Landon - good point.  i dont know of a common notation if several choices tie for max.  in the context of decoding, picking any of that subset results in the same Prob(error), and i believe in practice the decoder is just hardwired to pick one of them.

Comment: From your answer, for the general case, I arrived at...

$$
d\left(y\right) = \min\left(\underset{x\in R_X}{\operatorname{argmax}}\left(P\left[X = x\;|\;Y = y\right] \right)\right)
$$